# jQuery Fade between two opacities

Tags: jquery, fade

I have a problem with fading between two opacities in jQuery. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#header').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo(2000, 1.0);
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo(2000, 0.4);
    });
});
<div id="header" style="background: black; height: 100px;width: 100px; opacity: 0.4;"></div>
```

The problem is when I move my mouse over the `#header` element it will start fading from 0 to 1. But I want to do from 0.4 to 1 effect. Is it possible to do it with jQuery?

EDIT: Oh looks like my Chromium 8 have problem with that. All works fine in firefox. Any suggestions on how to fix that in this early version of chrome?

EDIT2: Works fine after including [jQuery Animate Enchanced](http://playground.benbarnett.net/jquery-animate-enhanced/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).css('opacity', '0.4').fadeTo(2000, 1.0)
```

**Full code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#header').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).css('opacity', '0.4').fadeTo(2000, 1.0);
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo(2000, 0.4);
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
$('#header').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).css('opacity', .4).fadeTo(2000, 1.0)
    }
)
...
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ys2rr/)